# ISPConfig set up login page URL

Tags: 16.04, hosting

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server with ISPConfig 3.1.

I set up many websites and emails, but I would like to log in to the server or account through an URL like domain.com/ispconfig (pretty much like cpanel).

How can I set up this URL in order to access to the ISPConfig login page for clients?

Answer (score 0):

It depands on your webserver software. There are several approches. If you are using apache one way would be the use of mod_rewrite. I personally prefer the use of directory aliases. You can find all ISP site configurations files in /etc/httpd/conf/sites-available.

Also take a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html

Comment: I'm using Apache. In the case of directory aliases, does it work for HTTPS connections ?

Comment: Depends on you configuration, but usually it does work.